# Select & Copy Only Non Blank Cells in Excel VBA, Don't Overwrite

Tags: vba, excel

I cant seem to find a solution for my application after endless searching. This is what I want to do:

I have cells in one excel sheet that can contain a mixture of dates and empty cells in one column. I want to then select the cells that have only dates and then copy them to a corresponding column in another sheet. They must be pasted in exactly the same order as in the first sheet because there are titles attached to each row. I do get it right with this code:

```
'Dim i As Long

'For i = 5 To 25

'If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("RMDA").Range("D" & i)) Then _

Sheets("Overview").Range("D" & i) = Sheets("RMDA").Range("D" & i)

'Next i
```

However, the dates in the first sheet are being updated on a daily basis and it can be that one title has not been updated (on another day) on the first sheet because the user has not checked it yet. If I leave it blank and If I follow the same procedure then it will "overwrite" the date in the second sheet and make the cell blank, which I do not want. I hope I was clear. Can someone please help me?

Regards

Comment: Did you mean to have commented out all lines of code other than Sheets("Overview").Range("D" & i) = Sheets("RMDA").Range("D" & i)?

Also just because a cell is blank does not mean that it is empty

Comment: @EdHunter  I performed an *EDIT* on the post and left the astricks in place.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this very easily (and with little code) utilizing Excel's built-in `AutoFilter` and `SpecialCells` methods.

```
With Sheets("RMDA").Range("D4:D25")

    .AutoFilter 1, "<>"

    Dim cel as Range
    For Each cel In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        Sheets("Overview").Range("D" & cel.Row).Value = cel.Value

    Next

    .AutoFilter

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like.  This will give you the non blanks from the range, there may be an easier way... hope it helps

```
Sub x()

Dim rStart As Excel.Range
Dim rBlanks As Excel.Range

Set rStart = ActiveSheet.Range("d1:d30")
Set rBlanks = rStart.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

Dim rFind As Excel.Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim rNonBlanks As Excel.Range

For i = 1 To rStart.Cells.Count
    Set rFind = Intersect(rStart.Cells(i), rBlanks)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        If rNonBlanks Is Nothing Then
            Set rNonBlanks = rFind
        Else
            Set rNonBlanks = Union(rNonBlanks, rFind)
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because a cell is blank does not mean that it is actually empty.

Based on your description of the problem I would guess that the cells are not actually empty and that is why blank cells are being copied into the second sheet.

Rather than using the "IsEmpty" function I would count the length of the cell and only copy those which have a length greater than zero

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 5 To 25

If Len(Trim((Sheets("RMDA").Range("A" & i)))) > 0 Then _

Sheets("Overview").Range("D" & i) = Sheets("RMDA").Range("D" & i)

Next i
```

Trim removes all spaces from the cell and then Len counts the length of the string in the cell. If this value is greater than zero it is not a blank cell and therefore should be copied.